# Interpretation of $\frac{\partial }{\partial p_1}Q_1(p_1, p_2)/\frac{\partial}{\partial p_2} Q_1(p_1, p_2)$

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, supply-and-demand, industrial-organisation

I am interested in an economic interpretation for the ratio of partial derivatives of a demand function $Q_1(p_1, p_2)$, which is
\begin{equation}
t=\frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial p_1}Q_1(p_1, p_2)}{\frac{\partial}{\partial p_2}Q_1(p_1, p_2)}.
\end{equation}
Assume the goods are complements so that both partial derivatives are negative.

This has the same form as the MRS in consumer theory, but the intuition does not readily apply.

I have been thinking about this as the ratio of demand sensitivities: if $t>1$ then the demand for good 1 is more sensitive to changes in $p_1$; if $t<1$, then the demand for good 1 is more sensitive to changes in $p_2$.

I would also say this is somewhat related to the cross price elasticity of demand, but the formula is not the same.

Any interpretations or intuitions would be great!

Answer (score 7):

One interpretation I can offer. The demand function can be expressed as:

$$Q_1 = Q_1(p_1,p_2)$$

Let us take the total differential:

$$dQ_1 = \frac{\partial Q_1(p_1,p_2)}{\partial p_1}dp_1+\frac{\partial Q_1(p_1,p_2)}{\partial p_2}dp_2$$

Assume that $Q_1$ remains unchanged with respect to a change in prices. This implies that $dQ_1=0$. Solving the equation:

$$\frac{d p_2}{d p_1} = - \frac{\frac{\partial Q_1(p_1,p_2)}{\partial p_1}}{\frac{\partial Q_1(p_1,p_2)}{\partial p_2}}$$

The above expression implies the following (since both partial derivatives are negative):

$$t = \left|\frac{dp_2}{dp_1}\right| = \frac{\frac{\partial Q_1(p_1,p_2)}{\partial p_1}}{\frac{\partial Q_1(p_1,p_2)}{\partial p_2}}$$

$t$ can be interpreted as follows: if good 1 became more expensive, how much would the price of good 2 need to change (decrease) such that the demand for good 1 remains unchanged.

Mathematically, $t$ represents the magnitude of the slope at ($p_1,p_2$) on the level curve when we fix $Q_1$.